# Being able to submit a form and control field visibility at the same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to print errors to the screen within a div and keep them there until there is a successful transmission. However this will not allow a submission.   I can submit if I remove the e.preventDefault() but then the content of the error div flashes and vanishes.  Is there a way to do both?

```
 $("#submitButton").click(function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#message').hide();

 //processing errors

   if (errorstr !== "") {
            var d;
            d = document.getElementById("message");
            d.innerHTML = errorstr;
           $('#message').show();
        }
        else {

            $('#message').hide();
        }
   }


  @using (Html.BeginForm(...)
  {
    <div id="message"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" class="form-input"/>
  }
```

Comment: Use ajax to submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use ajax or `URL.Action` to submit the form.

ajax way:

```
function submitForm()
{
   $.ajax({
      url: 'Controller/Action',
      data: { } // your data
   }).done(function() {
      alert('Success'); 
   });
}
```

Usage:

```
if (errorstr !== "") {
            var d;
            d = document.getElementById("message");
            d.innerHTML = errorstr;
           $('#message').show();
        }
        else {
             submitForm();
            $('#message').hide();
        }    }
```

`URL.Action` way:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + data;
```

Comment: Where would the field validation go with the ajax call?  Inside the click function just above it?

Comment: Inside the click function after validation.

if (errorstr !== "") {
            var d;
            d = document.getElementById("message");
            d.innerHTML = errorstr;
           $('#message').show();
        }
        else {
            // here you can call submitForm();
            $('#message').hide();
        }
   }

Comment: Sorry but could you edit your answer and add that?  I don't get exactly where?

Comment: The submit method is tied to a click of the button.  Will that not work for this?

Comment: You can directly call the ajax function. Don't need to use another function like submitForm. It's optional.

Comment: You can follow this article to understand. It's easy. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-serialize-form-data-into-a-model/